# Function not found in C++

Tags: c++

I am using sublime text 2 and I am trying to program bubble sort, and every time I run the code below it gives me an error on `bubbleSort(num[5], terms);` the error is

ERROR: no matching function for call to 'bubbleSort'.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int arr[], int term) {
    for(int i = 0; i < term; ++i) {
        for(int index = 0; index < term-i-1; ++index) {
            if(arr[index] < arr[index + 1]) {
                int swap;
                swap = arr[index];
                arr[index] = arr[index + 1];
                arr[index + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int counter = 0; counter < term; counter++) {
        cout << arr[counter] << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Hi in this program I will do bubble sort" << endl;
    cout << "The numbers are 2, 9, 5, 10, 6"<< endl;
    int num[5] = {2, 9, 5, 10, 6};
    int terms = sizeof (num) / sizeof (num[0]);
    bubbleSort(num[5], terms);

    //answer = [2, 5, 6, 9, 2, 10]
}
```

Comment: `bubbleSort(num[5], terms);` -> `bubbleSort(num, terms);`

Comment: Try: `bubbleSort(num, terms);`

Comment: `num[5]` is an element of `num[]` array. Write `bubbleSort(num, terms)`.

Comment: [Find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and reread the chapter on arrays.

Comment: @Shubham Actually `num[5]` is *not* an element in the `num` array, as the index is out of bounds.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice I will try it

Comment: ***ERROR: no matching function for call to 'bubbleSort'.*** if you read the entire error message carefully it should have told you the problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oh yes. `num[5]` will be out of bounds because there are only 5 elements (thus, valid indices [0, 4]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a good question should be accompanied by a complete example of the compiler error, this answer should be fine.

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int term) {
  // ...
}
```

It's a function which accepts an array of integers as first parameter and an integer as second one.

When you try to invoke it with:

```
int num[5] = {2, 9, 5, 10, 6};
// ...
bubbleSort(num[5], terms);
```

You're passing `num[5]` which is not an array of integer, but it should be an *element* of the array `num`, then an integer itself.

In short you're calling the function passing

```
 bubbleSort(INT, INT);
```

and not, as requested by the function

```
 bubbleSort(ARRAY_INT, INT);
```

That' why the compiler doesn't find a function which names `bubbleSort` and accept two integers.

## Additional note

It's a little be out of context, but I want to suggest you to improve your C++ base skills, because the expression:

```
num[5]
```

It's perfectly wrong in your code, because it tries to access to the 6-th element in the array (which is composed by only 5 elements), that'll produce an out-of-bound behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me now I know that I am supposed to use

```
bubbleSort(num, terms);
```

Comment: A little insight as to why this happens would be amazing for any other users with this problem in the future.